# why java supports function overloading for primitive data types?

Tags: java

while going through Autoboxing and unboxing in java, i learned that java converts primitive data types to Wrapper Class and vice versa whenever needed. e.g. if function is taking `Integer` as parameter if we pass value as `1` then java compiler will convert it to `new Integer(1)`. now below is my case.

```
public class JavaTest 
{

    public static void Test(Integer integer)
    {
        System.out.println("in Integer");
    }

    public static void Test(int integer)
    {
        System.out.println("in int");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test(1);
    }
}
```

in this case java should have thrown compile time exception. but it compiles successfully and prints below result

> in int

if i removes the Test(int integer) method then java gives me result

> in integer

so my question is why java is allowing such function overloading ?

Comment: no its not duplicate

Comment: yeah, it kinda is. you need to first understand the difference between class  and primitives types.

Comment: I think it's similar but not a duplicate - look at the context  here.

Comment: An example of this is `List<Integer>` where `remove(1)` and `remove((Integer) 1)` don't do the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109231/method-overload-resolution-in-java

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123247/integer-and-int-duality

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940321/method-overloading-with-primitives-and-their-wrappers

Answer (score 4):

Java allows such overloading for backwards compatibility.

Since auto-boxing and auto-unboxing was introduced in Java 5.0, the first stage of method overload resolution attempts to find a matching method without using auto-boxing and auto-unboxing.

Therefore, only the method that takes an `int` argument is found in your example. When you remove that method, no match is found in the first stage of method overload resolution, and the second stage uses auto-boxing in order to match the method that takes an `Integer` argument.

> [15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)
>
> The remainder of the process is split into three phases, **to ensure compatibility with versions of the Java programming language prior to Java SE 5.0**. The phases are:
>
> 1. The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution **without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion**, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>
>    **This guarantees that any calls that were valid in the Java programming language before Java SE 5.0 are not considered ambiguous as the result of** the introduction of variable arity methods, **implicit boxing and/or unboxing**. However, the declaration of a variable arity method (§8.4.1) can change the method chosen for a given method method invocation expression, because a variable arity method is treated as a fixed arity method in the first phase. For example, declaring m(Object...) in a class which already declares m(Object) causes m(Object) to no longer be chosen for some invocation expressions (such as m(null)), as m(Object[]) is more specific.
> 2. The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while **allowing boxing and unboxing**, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.
>
>    This ensures that a method is never chosen through variable arity method invocation if it is applicable through fixed arity method invocation.
> 3. The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

Comment: It is discouraged to answer duplicate questions as per the FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled. One should search for appropriate duplicates and vote to close instead.